# Determining recurrence relation from recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion

I got the following recursive algorithm and was asked to find its recurrence relation.

```
int search(int A[], int key, int min, int max)
{
    if (max < min)      // base case
       return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
    else
    {
       int mid = midpoint(min, max);

       if (A[mid] > key)    
          return search(A, key, min, mid-1);
       else if (A[mid] < key)
          return search(A, key, mid+1, max);
       else
          return mid;       // key found
    }
}
```

The solution is `T(n) = T(n/2) + 1` but I am not sure why is it `T(n/2)` ? and why is it `+ 1`? Is `+ 1` because recursion takes constant time? or what? Could anyone understand the solution?

Comment: What would you think the solution would be and why?

Comment: That solution is provided by our lecturer, but I am not sure how did he get that solution.

Comment: So, that's why I am asking what would you expect the answer to be? If you can't find one, then it's time to do some further reading. If you come up with a wrong answer, post it here so we can help. The solution lies in `given a set of data with length 'n', how many times will it take for the algorithm to exit` Here is an document with some examples: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rweba/algf09/solverecurrencesSF.pdf

Comment: Another tip: it's important to identify the variables which make the algorithm 'go'. Any constants can be ruled out (seems trivial but I have seen people getting headaches about dummy variables), and some variables might be derivative of the actual input. For example: `int A[]` is not doing much, It's length on the other hand does.

Comment: Btw; it's been a while for me so maybe I am mistaken ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the URL. That was a bit helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is an implementation of binary search. In binary search, at each recursive call you break the sorted array into half, then search for the element in the left part of the array if the element is smaller than the middle element, or search the right part of the array if the element is bigger than the middle element or stop if what you are looking for is the middle element.

Now if n shows the number of elements in your sorted array, whenever you break it into two almost same size arrays, your problem size decreases to n/2, and since you only call the search function once either way on a n/2 array, you can easily say that :

> T(n) = T(n/2)+O(1)

The O(1) addition is because of the if you run to check in which condition you are.

Comment: Just by inspecting the code (without any prior knowledge of binary search algorithm), how do we get to know about n/2 ? is it the midpoint calculation?

Comment: well, to answer this question, you should make sure that you know what n is actually! n is the number of elements in your input array, And it is also the parameter that determines the size of your problem. Now if you break that array in half, as your code does the size of the problem gets to n/2, and therefore you get n/2 in calculation. As for your problem in understanding the recurrence relation, you cannot expect to not understand the code and but be able to calculate its complexity! I think if you really understand what "min" and "max" parameters are in your function, you are good to go.